# Stop DIR command searching after first hit is found

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In CMD.EXE I can search for something using `DIR` - take the below example:

```
DIR C:\*EXCEL.EXE /A:-D /B /S
```

Although it will take a while to get through the whole structure of the C:\ drive, the first match is relatively quick.

**Q:** Is there a way to *automatically* stop the command from continuing the search once a hit has been found?

I'm asking because I actually want to shell a cmd prompt and read the StdOut to another script, but there will be a very long pause if I wait for the entire search to finish.

Comment: What you need is something like `head -1` to take only the first line. Probably pretty easy in Powershell. Is that an option you could use?

Comment: Potentially - I think I can use the same method to read the output from PowerShell, but not too sure on the syntax to use for the search _within_ PowerShell

Comment: There are ways to run a command like `dir` in a separate process (`start`), which could be killed at a certain point, but I have no idea how to get the output line by line; redirection does not work as it waits until the command has finished...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't stop `dir`, but you can use anoter method:

```
for /r "c:\" %%i in (excel.exe) do (echo -- %%i & goto :eof)
```

Comment: You mean `*excel.exe` like the OP?

Comment: This is giving me a LOT of output which wouldn't be good as I'm using a `StdOut.ReadAll()` method in my script.

Comment: `for /r` continues looping even after `goto :EOF` is reached.  It stops outputting matches, but the hard drive activity continues. I tested `for /R`, `dir /s /b`, `forfiles /s`, and `where /r`.  I'm still looking for a way to recurse and break after the first match, but it will probably involve a `goto` loop.  The best solution to OP's specific problem might be to examine the registry to determine the installed location of Office, but I'm still curious to find a solution to the recursion question.

Comment: I've managed to get this working, it was missing the asterisk as @aschipfl pointed out. It runs a lot faster than DIR so I'll take this as the answer. Cheers!

Comment: @MacroMan it probably runs faster because of hard drive caching.  It'll probably crawl again after your next reboot.  It probably is the best solution, though.  `goto` loops are slower than just letting a `for /R` complete its looping.

Comment: @rojo the actual script is looking for an executable that isn't registered in the system registry so I can't use that method - that was actually my first attempt and I was using WinAPI. Hence using this instead

Answer (score 0):

This by far has been the fastest way to do this that I have found.

Run this to get the location...(Way faster than dir)

`where /r %systemdrive% inventor.exe`

If you actually want to use the output run this...

`where /r %systemdrive% inventor.exe > %userprofile%\loctest.txt`

Then run this to set what ever variable you want to use. 
NOTE: (Remember only use 1 % if you are running this manually instead of in a .bat or .cmd)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in (%userprofile%\loctest.txt) do (set testvar=%%G)
```

You can then run an echo %testvar% to see the value...

[Here is what is looks like from the command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gZrv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I came to this chat searching a way to cd to a directory with a given partial name; based on the Stephan's suggestion above, using a batch file this seems to work nicely for me:
in cww.bat::

```
for /D /r "." %%i in (*%1*) do (cd %%~pfxi & goto :eof)
```