# vba word - find application on system and launch it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an application, user can install it on any folder in his/her computer how can I find my application on his computer(where it is installed and launch it)

```
Dim path
path = "path/to/myApplication.exe" 'path to myApplication is unknown I need to find it
Shell """" & path & """", vbNormalFocus
```

Is there any easy way I can find where user has installed my application on his computer, in windows

Comment: Is it actually installed on the system, or just an .exe file?

Comment: It is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37213980/7857211) offers a great solution to your problem.

You can always [iterate recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20701272/7857211) through the file system, but there are obvious downsides to this method (time, permissions, networks etc.).

Comment: thanks david, I used [.Run](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html) command to hide the cmd window, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32298415/4233036